# if statement in wrong order, not sure whats wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
while True:
    try:

        enterName = input("Enter file name:") + ".txt"
        openFile = open(enterName,"r")
        read = openFile.readlines()
        openFile.close()
        puzzle = [] 
        for lines in read: 
            puzzle.append(lines.strip())

        square(puzzle) 



    print ("\nFile loading...")
    print ("\nFile:")
    for letters in puzzle:
        print (letters)

    checked(puzzle)
```

The def nChar isn't working when I am using it in try:

When I enter the file exxample:

```
ABC
BCA
CAB
```

It straightaway says "File does not have n different characters."
What have I done wrong? Is the if statement in the wrong position or?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @MangeshGhotage I fixed it , but currently just having a different error which im trying to work on.

Comment: New post for new error. Post/accept the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nChar()` function *always* returns `None`:

```
def nChar(nc):
    grid = len(nc)
    for char in nc:
        if len(set(char)) != grid: 
            return
```

`None` is considered false in boolean contexts.

Have your function return `True` or `False` instead:

```
def nChar(nc):
    grid = len(nc)
    for line in nc:
        if len(set(line)) != grid: 
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: ah ok thankyou. I did that and I ran the program and I ran into another problem. When I enter the file name . e.g file1 it keeps asking for the file name again instead of printing it out and going through other save functions etc.

Comment: That's better posted as a new question; this specific problem has been solved. Make sure you produce a proper [mcve]; in this question you posted incomplete code (no `except` block), making it impossible to see what is going wrong with your file handling.